# Print out n elements of a list each time a function is run

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of strings and I need to create a function that prints out n elements of the list each time it is run.
For instance:

```
book1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
```

Expected output first time I run the function if `n = 5`:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

second time:

```
f
g
h
i
j
```

I tried this:

```
def print_book(book):
    printed = book
    while printed != []:
        for i in range(0, len(book), 5):
            new_list = (book[i:i+5])
            for el in new_list:
                print(el)
        break
    del(printed[i:i+10])
```

And I get either the entire list printed out, or I end up printing first n elements each time I run the function.
If this question has already been asked, please point it out to me, I would really apreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to exhaust the iterator once or want to iterate through the list multiple times?

Comment: @theProgrammer I guess either way would work, as long as I get only n consecutive elements printed out (and not the same 5 elements each time and not the entire list)

Comment: @VarvaraLitvinova do you want to preserve the elements in your list. or is it ok to delete the elements as we iterate ?

Comment: If you want to do this in a clean way, you need to create some kind of data structure with a state, aka an object. A closure would work too. In that case, you would have a function that would take your list as an input and return a function that delivers a part of the list every time you invoke it.

Comment: As nilo says you have to rely on storing state between function calls. You either do this changing a global variable (affecting global state), which is very simple but discouraged as a programming practice, or you store the state locally in your function or object. This can be done (at least) with a custom class, or a closure, or an iterator, or taking advantage of mutable default arguments. I am upvoting this question because it has the potential to trigger so many diverse answers with different techniques, making it interesting.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri for me either way would work, but as nilo and progmatico pointed out, preserving elements is way better. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can try the following user function which applied to iterator `book`

```
def print_book(book):
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < 5:
        try:
            print(next(book))
        except StopIteration:
            print("You have reached the end!")
            break
        cnt += 1
```

such that

```
>>> bk1 = iter(book1)
>>> print_book(bk1)
a
b
c
d
e
>>> print_book(bk1)
f
g
h
i
j
>>> print_book(bk1)
k
l
m
n
o
>>> print_book(bk1)
You have reached the end!
```

Answer (score 5):

A common approach is a generator expression. A generator expression yields it value when it is needed and hence, the whole list would not be created at once

A solution to your problem might be this

```
book1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']

def yield_book(book1):
    for i in book1:
        yield i;
                
def print_n_item(gen, n):
    count = 0
    for i in gen:
        if count == n:
            return
        print(i)
        count += 1
        
gen = yield_book(book1)
print_n_item(gen, 5) # prints a,  b,  c, d, e
print_n_item(gen, 5) # prints f,  g,  h,  i,  j
print_n_item(gen, 5) # prints k,  l,  m,  n,  o
```

This approach exhausts the iterator and hence can be used once,  in order to iterate again,  you have to call `yield_book` to return a new `generator`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, you really want to encapsulate the state in some kind of data structure. The class approach:

```py
class Printer:
    def __init__(self, book, n=5):
        self.book = book
        self.index = 0
        self.n = n

    def print(self):
        index = self.index
        self.index += self.n
        for t in self.book[index:self.index]:
            print(t)


book1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
printer = Printer(book1)
printer.print()
print()
printer.print()
```

Result:

```sh
a
b
c
d
e

f
g
h
i
j
```

Comment: Compared to @ThomasIsCoding's solution, in this one you basically implement your own iterator. Although one should generally not reinvent the wheel, it's a good way of learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a specific function, taking advantage of the behavior of a mutable default argument in a function (you can use as a memory of the function):

```py
book1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
    
def print_books(n, i=[0]):
    list(map(print, book1[i[0]:i[0] + n]))
    i[0] = (i[0] + n) if i[0] < len(book1) else 0

print_books(5)
print()
print_books(5)
```

`n` is the number of the items of the list to print and it is reset to 0 once the end of the list is reached; `i` is a list used to store the index of the first element not printed yet.

You should avoid this feature because it can generate strange and unexpected behaviors (take a look [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)), but it can be used to save the state of a function and I thought it worths a mention here.

Answer (score 1):

And as a function factory

```
book_1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']

def printer_factory(book, n = 5):
    i = 0
    def printer():
        nonlocal i
        stop = min(i+n, len(book))
        while i < stop:
            print(book[i])
            i += 1
    return printer

printer_1 = printer_factory(book_1)

printer_1()
printer_1()
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with nilo.  Below is a solution based on his response.  In this solution, you will go back to the beginning of the list once you loop the whole list.

```
book1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']

class Printer:
    def __init__(self, book):
        self.index = 0
        self.book = book

    def print(self, n):

        for i in range(0, n):
            print(self.book[self.index % len(self.book)])
            self.index += 1


book = Printer(book1)
book.print(5)
print("")
book.print(5)
print("")
book.print(7)
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e

f
g
h
i
j

k
l
m
n
o
a
b
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not made much edits to your programme.So this can be a little useful for you in understanding.

```
book1= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
def print_book(book,a,n):
    printed = book
    if printed != []:
    
        new_list=[]#i have created a list
        for i in range(a,n+1):
            new_list.append(book[i])#append is used to add elements to list
        
        for el in new_list:
                print(el)
    
print_book(book1,0,4)#prints a,b,c,d,e
print_book(book1,5,9)#prints f,g,h,i,j
```