# How to print the next row every time a function runs? (openpyxl)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, nested-loops

The overall project I am doing is that I am taking values from a specific row and column in an excel document using openpxyl and filling out a form on a webpage. I fill the form, then save it, then fill out the next form with the **next row of values from the excel document.**

Excel looks like this:

```
First Name         Last Name         DOB

George             Hill              9/9/99
Sam                Genius            8/8/88
Bill               Smith             7/7/77
```

I want to run the below function three times and each time it runs prints out the next row:

```
 def AddFirstName():
     for i in range(3):
       for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=3,max_col=1):
         for cell in row:
            print(cell.value)
                
            break
       break  # Tried to use breaks to break the loop so it only prints once for each loop

AddFirstName()
AddFirstName()
AddFirstName()
```

OR just run it outside the function like this:

```
    for i in range(3):
       for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=3,max_col=1):
         for cell in row:
            print(cell.value)
                
            break
       break  # Tried to use breaks to break the loop so it only prints once for each loop
```

This prints:

```
George
George
George
```

How do I fix this so that it prints:

```
George             
Sam                
Bill
```

Comment: You state "I want to run the below function three times and each time it runs prints out the next row" Why are you looping rows in the function? You want to call the function 3 times so each time the function should only read one row. Since the function holds no count you'd send an argument on each call that would specify which row to read and return. ?

Comment: Because I am filling out a form on a web page, I want each form to have the next row of information. So I am trying to figure how to loop through the rows so that each form gets the next row of information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65544645/print-out-n-elements-of-a-list-each-time-a-function-is-run)

Basically, it will print out the number of rows I want pending on the amount of times I run the function.

```
listofnames = [
              ['George'],
              ['Bill'],
              ['Mike']]

def print_names(name):
cnt = 0
while cnt < 1:
    try:
        print(next(name))
    except StopIteration:
        print("You have reached the end of the list!")
        break
    cnt += 1

first_name = iter(listofnames)

for i in range (3):
    print_names(first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer based on your comments and what you are looking to accomplish.

This solution leverages a Closures. Closures are nested functions, where an outer function def encloses an inner function def, and where the outer function returns the inner function.  Variables declared as nonlocal in the inner function keep their values from call to call of the inner function in the callers namespace.  In this example, the inner function has 2 nonlocals.  One to track the total number of rows processed and the other is a copy of the iterator.

A closure may see like a lot of work for your example, but I think it makes your code more portable and usable in the long run.  All of intelligence for processing N rows is in the inner function.  Change it there and all 'instances' of the closure's behavior are updated as well.

Also, instead of 'try', I am using unittest.mock.sentinel because it's a lot less typing than try:... And, it looks cleaner.

```
import unittest.mock
from unittest.mock import sentinel

sheetData = [
    ['George'],
    ['Bill'],
    ['Mike']
]

def set_iter(sheet_data):
    total_rows = 0
    sheet_data_iter = iter(sheet_data)
    # Create a closure that will track the total number of times we have called
    # the iterator. A closure may seem like a lot of extra work in this example,
    # but it shows how usefule they can be when you variables in a function
    # to persist after they have been called.
    def get_next(rows_to_print):
        # Declaring total_rows as nonlocal means this function uses the total_rows from
        # the enclosing fucntion, and that this variable will keep its value in subsequent
        # calls to the this function after set_iter is called.
        nonlocal total_rows
        nonlocal sheet_data_iter
        rows_printed = 0
        while rows_printed < rows_to_print:
            rows_printed += 1
            print(f"Printing Row: {rows_printed} of {rows_to_print} Rows to Print this time through.")
            row_data = next(sheet_data_iter, sentinel.END_OF_ITERATION)
            if row_data == sentinel.END_OF_ITERATION:
                print("There are no more items to iterate over")
                return None
            else:
                # row_data = next(sheet_data_iter)
                print(f"0th Element of Row With Index: {total_rows} is: '{row_data[0]}'")
                # total_rows maintains it's value through subsequent calls to the returned
                # get_next function.  It's keeps track of the total number of times the
                # iterator has been called.
                total_rows += 1
        return True
    # get_next(row_count)
    return get_next


# print_next_n_rows is a function, as returned by set_iter()
print_next_n_rows = set_iter(sheetData)
# another_print_n_rows is also a function, and it encapsulate a fresh iterator,
# it tracks separate from print_next_n_rows
another_print_n_rows = set_iter(sheetData)

# This line should print George
if print_next_n_rows(1):
    print("There were still rows.\n")
else:
    print("Caught out of rows...\n")


# This should print the next 2 lines
if print_next_n_rows(2):
    print("There were still rows.\n")
else:
    print("Caught out of rows...\n")


# This should print the first 2 lines...
if another_print_n_rows(2):
    print("There were still rows.\n")
else:
    print("Caught out of rows...\n")


# This should catch the end of the list
if print_next_n_rows(1):
    print("There were still rows.\n")
else:
    print("Caught out of rows...\n")
```

Here is the output from the above script:

```
Printing Row: 1 of 1 Rows to Print this time through.
0th Element of Row With Index: 0 is: 'George'
There were still rows.

Printing Row: 1 of 2 Rows to Print this time through.
0th Element of Row With Index: 1 is: 'Bill'
Printing Row: 2 of 2 Rows to Print this time through.
0th Element of Row With Index: 2 is: 'Mike'
There were still rows.

Printing Row: 1 of 2 Rows to Print this time through.
0th Element of Row With Index: 0 is: 'George'
Printing Row: 2 of 2 Rows to Print this time through.
0th Element of Row With Index: 1 is: 'Bill'
There were still rows.

Printing Row: 1 of 1 Rows to Print this time through.
There are no more items to iterate over
Caught out of rows...
```

hth,

David

Comment: I have everything properly indented already like you showed. It just didn't copy paste right to stack overflow! Good thinking though. If I just get rid of the first loop and print the output of:  "for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=3, max_col=1):
        for cell in row:
            print(cell.value)"  It will print everything I want in that row so that isn't the issue

Comment: If you have an IDE that provides debugging, like Pycharm or similar, step through your program and watch the values of your objects and track where the `break` statements send you.

Comment: I see it just repeats the statement like I put in the post. I want to figure out how to run the loop once, print first row, and then continue to other functions in my programs, come back to this loop above and print the second row etc

Comment: The answer has been updated based on your comments above.